# it says "pxc" is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

i wrote the codes from a youtube tutorial.
codes:

```
import pygame

# itilaze
pygame.init()

# title and icon
icon = pygame.image.load("satanic.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("demo")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
playerImg = pygame.image.load("pixil-frame-0 (1).png")
Px = 370
Py = 480


def player(x,y):
   screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


# ekran boyutu
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# LOOP
running = True
while running:
   screen.fill((50, 3, 10))  # rgb
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           running = False

       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               Pxc = -0.5
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               Pxc = 0.5
       if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               Pxc = 0
   Px += Pxc
   player(Px,Py)  # adam
   pygame.display.update()
```

and i got this error but the guy in video didnt. here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonProject3/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    Px += Pxc
NameError: name 'Pxc' is not defined
```

it would be nice if you guys help me i started learning phyton today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pxy` is only set in the event loop. Hence, `Pxc` is never set if no event occurs. Initialize `Pxc` before the application loop:

```py
Pxc = 0              # <--- ADD THIS

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    Px += Pxc
```